# How to increment div value after cloning using clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, increment

I am trying to output the header as Group 1 , Group 2 and so on, after cloning the div.
However when I try to set the Group Name after clicking the button it gives me Group 1 whereas I want the first div to be Group 1 and then the first clone event will content Group 2.
I have tried several methods that are pasted over SO but that didn't give the result that I am looking for.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shafox/9xXfa/1/ that you can look.

[HTML]

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="">
        <span class="btn btn-primary addstage">Add Stage</span>
        <select id="selecttype">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">League</option>
            <option value="2">Knockout</option>
        </select>
        <div class="leaguegrp">
            <div class="league">

                <div class="groupnum"></div>

                <span class="btn btn-primary addStage">Add Group</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS]

```
        var i = 1;
$(".groupnum").each( function() {
    var i = 1;
    $(this).append("Group", +i);
    ++i;
    $(".addStage").click(function(){
        var leagueGroup = $(".league").last().clone();

        $(".leaguegrp").append(leagueGroup)
    });
});


$(".addstage").click(function() {
    $("#selecttype").show();
});
$("#selecttype").change(function() {
    $(".league")[$(this).val() == "1" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
$("#selecttype").change(function() {
    $(".knockout")[$(this).val() == "2" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
var grp = $(".groupnum").length;
//$(".groupnum").append("Group"+" "+ grp);
//console.log("Group"+" "+ grp);
```

[CSS]

```
#selecttype{display: none;}
```

Comment: Where is id="program-n" defined?

Comment: Is it just me or do the HTML and the javascript come from different projects?

Comment: I am working on different pages, and I am stupid. Sleepy eyes I guess. That's why the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9xXfa/2/

This is not the optimal way to do it, but if you don't want to change a major part of your code, just add this line after appending the node.

```
leagueGroup.find('.groupnum').text('Group '+ (leagueGroup.index() + 1))
```

This will set a group number depending of his index in the DOM.

**EDIT :**

I actually did not see that you had already a saved var, so you could do this instead :

```
leagueGroup.find('.groupnum').text('Group '+ i)
i++
```

Comment: This certainly works the way I wanted to. If this is not the optimal way. Could you please share what would be ? @Karl-André Gagnon

Comment: I edited my answer since i missed something, and im gonna post another comment soon with an optimised fiddle.

Comment: Okay, without going into the JS object, wich would be probly the best in the futur of your project (can't be sure since i don't know your entire project), this (http://jsfiddle.net/9xXfa/3/) is a little bit better (just a little) for 2 reasons. 1: every bouton now have the event handler and 2: you dont naviguate through the DOM to clone. You just navigate once on load. Sorry if I am not clear, but to what i mean is that the perfomance is better like that!

Comment: @ Karl-André Gagnon:: This is what my project looks like. With your help I have updated the js. There is some id clash.    http://jsfiddle.net/shafox/9xXfa/4/

Comment: If I update the id by incremental also, the href will not change, How to achieve that ?

Comment: I never worked with bootstrap, so i cant say anything for the performance, but here, i did something and it work : http://jsfiddle.net/9xXfa/5/ (same place where i did the clone thing)

Comment: :: Thanks Man. It was such a relief. I was trying that for a whole 2 hours. You saved me. Now I can go and sleep.

Comment: And sadly I can't upvote it. But I guess you know how I feeling right now.